# string vs JRaw for JSON as a string

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON which has a property `payload`. It holds a JSON as a string like this.

```
// json schema
{
    "id": "GUID",
    "type": "some type",
    "payload": "{\"name\": \"Smith\", \"age\": 30, ...}" // <- I get a json and serialize it to a string
}

// A C# class for the Json would be...
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public CustomType Type { get; set; }
    public string/JRaw/Anything else? { get; set; }
}
```

My question is what data type I should use for `payload`. `string` or `JRaw` can be used but

- Is there anything else that's better than these types?
- Is `JRaw` better than `string`? Why/Why not?

`Item` object will be returned by .NET Core API. A client app gets the response from the API then deserializes it to an object (`Item`).
`payload` value can be large. It can be more than 2 ~ 3MB or more.

Comment: IHMO it really depends on what you like to do next with this thing. But if you don't really care, leave it as string and otherwise make an `Item<T>` and deserialize the payload to this generic argument.

Comment: If you use `string` for your `payload` then its value will be *serialized* -- i.e. its JSON value will get escaped as a string when embedded in some outer JSON.  If you use `JRaw` (or any other `JToken`) for `payload` then the JSON will be embedded in the outer JSON as-is without escaping.  The question is, which do you want?  Also, I am not sure that Json.NET can deserialize `JRaw` directly.  You may want to declare it as `JToken` and actually use `JRaw`.

Answer (score 1):

Between JRaw and string this should be a string. `JRaw` is in `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace and this is not about Linq.

Having said that, you should just return the object:

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public CustomType Type { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```